# MS Excel VBA script

Tags: function, excel, syntax, vba

I haven't tried coding except in javascript in the past, however i'm pretty new.

I'm trying to create a macro for excel that will compare a the values in sheet1 in column B individually to corresponding column B in sheet2 to find a match. If no match is found the entire row is added to the bottom of the spreadsheet. any help on where to start would be appreciated.

I have 6 columns in the list

Comment: This is a very easy thing to do, you should give it a try or google your question at first, then had you have any problems post your question here. This could be called a 'lazy' question.

Comment: I did but the code i came up with was just embarrassing lol

Comment: Don't be embarrassed.  If you make a mistake and have to post a question, perhaps someone in the future will learn from it.  Either way, you are more likely to receive help on SO if you post your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key to what you are attempting is in understanding the nested Loops.

- Begin by looping through Sheet 1
- Set a temp Value for each row
- Begin loop of Sheet 2, each row comparing the temp Value.
- Use a boolean variable to track if there was a match or not
- At the end of the loop of Sheet 2, If there was no match
- Copy the row, by looping through the columns
- Continue looping through Sheet 1

Code:

```
Sub CopyNoMatch()

Dim lastSourceRow As Long
Dim source As String, target As String
Dim tempVal As String
Dim tRow As Long, lRow As Long, lCol As Long, nRow As Long
Dim match As Boolean

    source = "Sheet1"
    target = "Sheet2"

    lastSourceRow = Sheets(source).Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).row

    For lRow = 2 To lastSourceRow     'Loop through Rows on Sheet1
        match = False                 'Reset boolean test for each new row
        tempVal = Sheets(source).Cells(lRow, "B").Text      'Assign the tempValue to compare

        For tRow = 2 To lastTargetRow   'Loop through entire target sheet
            If Sheets(target).Cells(tRow, "B").Text = tempVal Then
                match = True
            End If
        Next tRow

        If match = False Then           'No Match found, copy row
            nRow = Sheets(target).Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).row + 1
            For lCol = 1 To 6       'Copy entire row by looping through 6 columns
                Sheets(target).Cells(nRow, lCol).Value = Sheets(source).Cells(lRow, lCol).Value
            Next lCol
    Next lRow

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! much appreciated. it seems to copy the entire first sheet to the second. however the copy part works great, trying to fix it now.

Comment: It's probably the assignment of TempVal.  Look at the revised code, and try it.  Open your LOCALS window and watch the values as they change.  match isn't being set to true.

Comment: I've played around with it for over an hour, not sure where im going wrong. the test keeps failing and stays false so the entire list is copied. If i use the same data set in the same order and change 1 row, it will only print the row the that is different.

Comment: are you using this line?  'tempVal = Sheets(source).Cells(lRow, "B").Text'

Comment: yup, i think that this for loop For tRow = 2 To lastTargetRow will cycle through and make match true however it wont exit the loop and continue it seems to continue the loop with every row from target and the value goes back to false.